# MySQL 6.3 - Create Procedure Error in Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a stored procedure but getting error. Stored Procedure is as given below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addSection (IN sectionname varchar(50), IN sectiondetail varchar(50)) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO inquiry (sectionname,sectiondetail,entrytime) VALUES (sectionname,sectiondetail,now()); 
END// delimiter;
```

But I am getting error as given below

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3  0.00026 sec

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3

Please help...

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following first and switch the delimiter to //:

```
delimiter //
```

Then run what you had with a minor modification (compare the last line):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addSection (IN sectionname varchar(50), IN sectiondetail varchar(50)) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO inquiry (sectionname,sectiondetail,entrytime) VALUES (sectionname,sectiondetail,now()); 
END//
```

Without switching delimiter, when the client sees the semicolon at the end of the insert statement, it thought the definition of the procedure ended there prematurely - that's what the syntax error was about.

You can always switch the delimiter back to ; by doing:

```
delimiter ;
```